# ColdFusion "OR" query allowing username or employee number for login

Tags: coldfusion

I have a log in page where I am trying to query the database and let the user login by either there `employee_number` or by there `user_name` using coldfusion to do so. Is it possible to add the OR employee_number in order to do so? If I remove the OR part it works with just the user name but I am trying to figure out how to let the user use either there user name or employee number. Then no matter which one they enter have the session go by the employee number. Like this `<cfset session.employee_number = userVerify.employee_number />`

```
<!--- Get all records from the database that match this users credentials ---> 
    <cfquery name="userVerify" datasource="test"> 
        SELECT  * 
        FROM    dbo.Users 
        WHERE user_name = '#user_name#' 
        AND  user_pass = '#user_pass#' 
        OR employee_number = '#employee_number#'
        AND user_pass = '#user_pass#'
    </cfquery> 

    <cfif userVerify.RecordCount> 
        <!--- This user has logged in correctly, change the value of the session.allowin value ---> 
        <cfset session.allowin = "True" /> 
        <cfset session.employee_number = userVerify.employee_number /> 

         <!--- Now welcome user and redirect to "index.html" ---> 
        <script> 
            alert("Welcome <cfoutput>#user_name#</cfoutput>, you have been successfully logged in!"); 
            self.location="../empty_page.html"; 
        </script> 
    <cfelse> 
        <!--- this user did not log in correctly, alert and redirect to the login page ---> 
        <script> 
            alert("Your credentials could not be verified, please try again!"); 
            self.location="Javascript:history.go(-1)"; 
        </script> 
        </cfif>
```

**PS I know not to use Select * this was just for testing purposes**

Comment: since it's user_name and employee_number are two different variables, why not put a `cfif` conditional in your `WHERE` clause to decide which one to use? e.g. `<cfif len(user_name)> use user_name <cfelse> use employee_number </cfif>`

Comment: PS - You might have omitted it for testing purposes, but use `cfqueryparam` for passing parameters to the database.

Comment: Also, although you do not explain what is wrong with the results when the `OR` is present, I suspect the lack of parenthesis are causing different results than you expected.  When the `where` condition contains a mix of both `AND` and `OR` operators you MUST use parenthesis to ensure the desired [order of evaluation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186992%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: @beloitdavisja Can you give an example I am not sure where to add that line. And what do you mean I normally use cfqueryparam to create a record this is just querying the record and matching the login

Comment: @DavidBrierton you should always always ALWAYS use `cfqueryparam` for any variable you pass to the database. It does not matter if you are creating a record or querying a record. I'll post a solution below for the query.

Comment: Not related to your question, but a javascript alert is a pretty annoying way of welcoming people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: Removed variable `employee_number` that was in original question since it is not actually a variable being passed in.

```
<cfquery name="userVerify" datasource="test">
    SELECT  employee_number
    FROM    dbo.Users
    WHERE   user_pass = <cfqueryparam value="#user_pass#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
            AND (
                user_name = <cfqueryparam value="#user_name#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
                OR 
                employee_number = <cfqueryparam value="#user_name#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
            )
</cfquery>
```

Comment: you wouldn't use Or if your wanting to do either or?

Comment: hmmm now I am just getting a blank screen

Comment: Guess it's a matter of design - would you  want to authenticate a user that entered an incorrect username but correct employee id? Why give them the option of entering both? Just let them enter one or the other on the login page.

Comment: oh the login has only two fields user_name and user_pass

Comment: but some how make user_name check employee_number or user_name for a match?

Comment: Ah. Well, the question had a variable `employee_name` so I assumed that was being passed to the page.

Comment: @DavidBrierton - Also, it is a good practice to A) Scope all variables ie `FORM.variableName` or `URL.variableName` B) Hash passwords instead of storing them in plain text and C) Avoid depending on JS only for redirection as it can be disabled.

Answer (score 3):

Put brackets around the `OR` to indicate the precedence:

```
<cfquery name="userVerify" datasource="test"> 
  SELECT  * 
  FROM    dbo.Users 
  WHERE   (  user_name       = <cfqueryparam value="#user_name#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" />
          OR employee_number = <cfqueryparam value="#employee_number#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" />
          )
  AND     user_pass = <cfqueryparam value="#user_pass#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" />
</cfquery>
```

(Also, use parameterised queries or you are just asking for SQL injection issues).

Or, to prevent them entering a valid name and invalid id combination (or vice versa) you could do:

```
<cfquery name="userVerify" datasource="test"> 
  SELECT  * 
  FROM    dbo.Users 
  WHERE   (   (   user_name       = <cfqueryparam value="#user_name#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" null = YesNoFormat( user_name IS "" ) />
              AND (  employee_number = <cfqueryparam value="#employee_number#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" null = YesNoFormat( employee_number IS "" ) />
                  OR <cfqueryparam value="#employee_number#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" null = YesNoFormat( employee_number IS "" ) /> IS NULL
                  )
              )
          OR  (  <cfqueryparam value="#user_name#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" null = YesNoFormat( user_name IS "" ) /> IS NULL
              AND employee_number = <cfqueryparam value="#employee_number#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" null = YesNoFormat( employee_number IS "" ) />
              )
          )
  AND     user_pass = <cfqueryparam value="#user_pass#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" />
</cfquery>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the loggedin user or employee details

```
<cfquery name="userVerify" datasource="test">
    SELECT  *
    FROM    dbo.Users
    WHERE   user_pass = <cfqueryparam value="#user_pass#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
         AND (
              user_name = <cfqueryparam value="#user_name#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
              OR 
              employee_number = <cfqueryparam value="#employee_number#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
            )
</cfquery>
```

Comment: This just repeats beloitdavisja's existing answer.